# Can you Teleport an unconscious target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

The spell *Teleport* states that you can teleport yourself and up to 8 willing creatures.

If a creature is unconscious, do they count as willing as they can't refuse, or unwilling as they can't give consent?